# GWT + Spring: NullPointerException on getServletContext() call

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm currently experimenting with GWT and Spring. More specifically I wanted to make the GreetingService sample to work with Spring on the server side. There are a couple of articles available for realizing this (I'm linking them here since some of you may be interested):

- http://ice09.wordpress.com/2009/05/25/google-app-engine-spring-3-and-jpa/
- http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/IntegratingWithSpring

Now I followed the mentioned instructions and when launching everything in the GWT hosted mode, the service on the server-side is also called successfully. But then before the response is being sent back to the client, I get the a NullPointerException when the getServletContext() is being called internally by some Spring framework class. The stacktrace is the following:

```
WARNING: Nested in org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:163)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.doUnexpectedFailure(RemoteServiceServlet.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.doPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:99)
    at com.jsdev.devbook.server.GWTController.handleRequest(GWTController.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:726)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:636)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:121)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:54)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:313)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:844)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:396)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
```

Here's the list of libs I deploy on my server / GWT hosted mode directory:

```
antlr-3.0.1.jar
appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.2.5.jar
appengine-api-labs-1.2.5.jar
commons-logging.jar
datanucleus-appengine-1.0.3.jar
datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar
geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar
gwt-servlet.jar
jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RC1.jar
spring-dao.jar
```

Even more info:
developing on Mac OSX, Java version 1.6.0_15.

Does someone have a clue what could be the problem here?

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the issue. The [GWTController](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/IntegratingWithSpring) implementation has to be made Servlet context aware. This can be done by implementing the `ServletContextAware` interface and overriding the `getServletContext()` and `setServletContext(..)` methods for letting the context be injected.

I just [published a blog post](http://juristr.com/blog/2009/09/gwt-meets-spring/) that describes the issue and provides the solution in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem and found that the `private transient ServletConfig config` field on `javax.servlet.GenericServlet` was null. GWT's `RemoteServiceServlet` was calling `log(...)` which in turn called `getServletName()` which NPE'ed due to `config` being null.

Our solution was to overide `getServletName()`:

```
public String getServletName() {
    // Override as GenericServlet does config.getServletName() which NPEs
    // as config is null. This causes NPEs when the log(...) methods are
    // invoked.
    return service.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

You could figure out why the ServletConfig is not being set or override some methods like we did.

Comment: thx for the hint, but it seems that my problem is even worse. I don't just have a NPE on the ServletName, but already on the ServletContext as a whole. Seems as if the problem is at the servlet container...Maybe a OSX problem with GWT?